# Is Avengers: Infinity War the first part of a two-part story?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Several years ago, Marvel Studios announced its list of planned movies for the Marvel Cinematic Universe far in advance.  Originally, the list included Avengers: Infinity War Part 1 with a 2018 release and Avengers: Infinity War Part 2 in 2019.

At some point, "Part 1" was removed from the title of Infinity War, and the 2019 movie just became "Untitled Avengers film."

I can see two possible explanations for this change:

1. The Infinity War story which was originally planned to span two films was condensed to a single film, and the movie in 2019 will be another story entirely.
2. The story is still in two parts as originally planned, and Marvel simply decided to give the second part a different title.

My question is, is there any indication which of these scenarios is the case?

Note:  I am trying to avoid spoilers, which is why I'm asking here rather than searching the net for an answer.  I just want to know if the filmmakers have said whether Infinity War is still part 1 of a two-part story or not.

Comment: @MrLister why are you excluding *Iron Man*, *The Incredible Hulk*, *Iron Man 2*, and *Thor*?

Comment: @MrLister but they are also part of the same storyline

Comment: @mrlister In Iron Man 2, we meet Black Widow and Nick Fury makes a comment about wanting Iron Man, but not Tony Stark, for the Avengers.

Comment: [spoilers, I guess] having seen Infinity War, it very much feels like a "part 1" kind of movie.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We won't really know for sure until we see how *Infinity War* ends if they make up a single "story", but Marvel Studios does not consider them a two-part movie. This was the primary reason for the name change in the first place.

When the two movies were first announced in 2014, its possible that someone at Marvel had an *idea* for a story that would span two movies, but at that point early on in the process, nothing concrete had been produced. The Russo brothers (the directors) have never made any comments to the effect that they "split up" the movie. Rather, they've been insistent that the two are separate movies that just happen to share a lot of characters and plot elements, as in your option #2:

> We wanted the movie to be very different and distinctive, you know. There's certainly cross-pollination between characters and some story-arcs, but you know, the first movie is very clearly Avengers: Infinity War and, in time, we will reveal what the second film is. <sup>[[src](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1547620/why-avengers-4-isnt-going-to-be-called-infinity-war-part-2-anymore)]</sup>

---

EDIT: Having seen the movie, I can say without any ambiguity and with 100% confidence that it was clearly the first part of a two-part story, and anyone trying to claim otherwise is just lying to you.

Comment: I’m currently wondering whether *Ant-Man and the Wasp* and *Captain Marvel* will effectively be continuations of the story in *Infinity War*, or whether either or both will be set before *Infinity War*. We’ve never had this kind of obvious continuity overlap in the MCU; I’m fascinated to see what they do with it.

Comment: I do think perhaps the retreat from describing the movies as *Infinity War Parts 1 and 2* was more a marketing decision (to avoid the audience thinking the MCU was going to be paused for a year between the movies, despite other movies being scheduled), rather than a creative decision about them being two separate movies. Clearly, the story of *Infinity War* is not finished by the end of the movie, and it seems unlikely that it’ll be finished anywhere other than next year’s *Avengers* movie.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite _Captain Marvel_ takes place in the 90s, so there's that.

Comment: @ZAD-Man: spoiler alert! But cool cool, that makes sense.

Comment: "Thanos will be back"

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   Yes, I think it's rather obvious that the only reason they didn't call it *Infinity War Part 1* is because they thought it would be bad for marketing and ticket sales.   (People don't want to go to a movie that's only part of the story or deliberately walk into a cliffhanger and have to wait a year, etc.)   Evidence to date suggests it was probably the right call.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   Also, it would probably be bad for DVD sales of Part 1.   You want to sell as many of the first movie as you can and then sell the set again later!   Who's going to buy just Part 1 rather than wait?

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Quite! Although I do wonder whether people would buy Part 1 to remind themselves before going to see Part 2. Harry Potter and the Hunger Games did parts 1 and 2 eh, wonder how it worked out for them.

Comment: @KutuluMike: “Having seen the movie, I can say without any ambiguity and with 100% confidence that it was clearly the first part of a two-part story” — I mostly agree, although I did also feel that Infinity War was a fairly complete story in and of itself, just one with a really big bummer of an ending. I didn’t feel like I was leaving halfway through the action.

Comment: Who knows? Maybe they will give it a different title.